# __init__ Constructor in Python

Tags: python, class, constructor, tuples, init

I am trying to write a constructor for a class "Block" which stores the coordinates of the center of the block (either as separate x- and y-coordinates or as a pair of numbers) and for the width and height of the block. The problem I am having is writing a **init** that can either take a tuple of coordinates for x,y or individual numbers for x and y.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 def __init__(self,(x,y),height,width):
```

Comment: Or else you can have default arguments for each having `0` as default value.

Comment: Can you not restrict the input to one or the other?

Comment: Note: in python3 you cannot have tuples in the argument list. In python you could indeed do `def f((x,y)):` but in python3 you have to do `def f(x_y): x,y = x_y` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Use keyword arguments:

```
class Blocks(object):
    def __init__(self, center=None, x=None, y=None, height=0, width=0):
        if center is None:
            # x and y must be set
            if x is None or y is None:
                raise TypeError('You must either specify a center or both x and y')
        else:
            # center is set, so x and y must not be
            if x is not None or y is not None:
                raise TypeError('You must either specify a center or both x and y')
            x, y = center
        # here you always have x and y set
```

Now you can use `Blocks(center=(10, 20))` or you can use `Blocks(x=10, y=20)`. Height and width have defaults, but can be overridden.

The alternative is to use a class method:

```
class Blocks(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, height, width):
        # here you always have x and y set

    @classmethod
    def from_center(cls, center, height, width):
        x, y = center
        return cls(x, y, height, width)
```

and use either:

```
block_one = Block(10, 20, 5, 5)
```

or

```
block_two = Block.from_center((10, 20), 5, 5)
```

Comment: what happens if a user passes both?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: error handling in the constructor, already added.

Comment: plus 1 but that is not pretty!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some default arguments and decide which to use depending on which ones are populated:

```
class Block(object):

    def __init__(self, height, width, coord_tuple=None, coord_x=None, coord_y=None):

        if coord_tuple:
            self.x = coord_tuple[0]
            self.y = coord_tuple[1]
        else:
            self.x = coord_x
            self.y = coord_y

        self.height = height
        self.width = width

        return

    def print_coord(self):
        print("Height: {}\nWidth: {}\nX: {}\nY: {}"
                .format(self.height, self.width, self.x, self.y))
        return

# tuple instantiations 
b1 = Block(1, 2, (1,2))
b2 = Block(3, 4, coord_tuple=(3,4))

# x/y instantiation
b3 = Block(5, 6, coord_x=5,coord_y=6)

b1.print_coord()
b2.print_coord()
b3.print_coord()
```

Produces:

> Height: 1
>   Width: 2
>   X: 1
>   Y: 2
>   Height: 3
>   Width: 4
>   X: 3
>   Y: 4
>   Height: 5
>   Width: 6
>   X: 5
>   Y: 6

Answer (score 0):

You could use a variable number of args:

```
class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, center, *args):
        if isinstance(center, tuple) and args and len(args) > 1:
            self.x, self.y = center
            self.w, self.h = args[:2]
        elif args and len(args) > 2:
            self.x = center
            self.y = args[0]
            self.w, self.h = args[1:3]
        else:
            raise Exception('Some exception')

b1 = Block(1, 1, 10, 10)
b2 = Block((2, 2), 10, 10)
```